# vue + count items date within 30days and display the total on the page

Tags: typescript, vue.js

How do i count the items by checking the date within 30 days from the current date?

Here is my sample code:

```
    <table width="100%"  border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>row</th>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Description</th>
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="(user,index) in bookData" v-bind:key="user.listData">
        <td>{{ user.index }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.item_id }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.category_id }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.r_date }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.description }}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    New Item within 30 days :
```

Dates output is like this "02/18/2022, 6:42:36 pm"

Im not sure if need to convert it on a dateformat, please advice and help how
to count it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a computed function to filter and count dates within 30 days

```
computed: {

...

    newItemsWithinThirtyDays() {
        return this.bookData.filter(user => {
            date = new Date(user.r_date)
            futureDate = (new Date())
            futureDate.setDate((new Date()).getDate() + 30)

            const msBetweenDates = Math.abs(date.getTime() - futureDate.getTime())
            return msBetweenDates / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) < 30
        }).length
    }

...

}
```

Use the property as followed: `{{ newItemsWithinThirtyDays }}`

Comment: Thanks but I am getting some errors on it . 
It says "Parentheses are required around the parameters of an arrow function definition". <br>

```
  private newItemsWithinThirtyDays(): void {
        return this.inventoryData.filter(user => {
            this.date = new Date(user.last_seen);
            this.futureDate = (new Date());
            this.futureDate.setDate((new Date()).getDate() + 30);
            const msBetweenDates = Math.abs(this.date.getTime() - this.futureDate.getTime());
            return msBetweenDates / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) < 30;
        }).length;
  }

Comment: Sounds like an ESLint error, wrap the `user` parameter with parentheses `(user)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `computed` property to filter your user and check if the `date` attribute is within 30 days.

To convert your date you can use the classic [Date constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and you can then compare if the date is between now and a date 30 days earlier.

Example:

```js
const bookData = [
  {
    r_date:"02/18/2022, 6:42:36 pm" 
  },
  {
    r_date:"05/05/2022, 6:42:36 pm" 
  },
  {
    r_date:"01/01/2022, 6:42:36 pm" 
  }
]

const checkDateWithin30Days = (date) => {
  const now = new Date()
  const oneMonthEarlier = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth()-1, now.getDate())
  console.log(new Date(date) > oneMonthEarlier)
  return new Date(date) > oneMonthEarlier
}

bookData.forEach(user => checkDateWithin30Days(user.r_date))
```

I've here compared `one month earlier` but you can make it as exactly 30 days earlier with

```js
const thirtyDaysEarlier = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate() - 30)
```

---

You can then include this inside your vue app

For example :

```js
new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: () => {
        return {
          bookData: [{
              r_date: "04/18/2022, 6:42:36 pm"
            },
            {
              r_date: "05/05/2022, 6:42:36 pm"
            },
            {
              r_date: "01/01/2022, 6:42:36 pm"
            }
          ]
        }
      },

      computed: {
        bookDataFilter() {
          return this.bookData.filter(user => this.checkDateWithin30Days(user.r_date))
          }
        },

        methods: {
          checkDateWithin30Days(date) {
            const now = new Date()
            const oneMonthEarlier = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() - 1, now.getDate())
            console.log(new Date(date) > oneMonthEarlier)
            return new Date(date) > oneMonthEarlier
          }
        }
      })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="user of bookDataFilter">
      {{ user }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  
  <div>Number of elements : {{ bookDataFilter.length }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How to do it in typescript ?

Comment: As classic TS with vue. You can tyoe the return type of the function : ` checkDateWithin30Days(date): boolean` etc.. You can check [the documentation for more information](https://fr.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html)